# Why this does not have a dot product on the right: $\int_\Omega \nabla \phi dx =\int_{\partial \Omega}\phi \nu ds$

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis, stokes-theorem, greens-theorem

My main concern is because, on the right side of the expression, there is a vector $\nu$, but there is not any dot product.

$$\int_\Omega \nabla \phi dx =\int_{\partial \Omega}\phi \nu ds$$

Where $\phi $ is a scalar function, and $\nu$ is the normal vector.

Where can I find solved exercises of applications of this theorem? I would like to get an intuition about the performed operations

Comment: Is $s$ a scalar?

Comment: @IshanDeo I think is the surface differential

Comment: @IshanDeo It is the surface differential, it is called the Gauss's formulas, It is in the Sandro Salsa (Partial differential Equations in Action, page 415) book

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The equation is correct if interpreted as $n$ scalar equations where $n$ is the dimension. I.e. writing $ \nu=(\nu_1,\dots, \nu_n)$, its true that (for nice enough functions $\phi$ and sets $\Omega$)

$$ \frac{\partial \phi}{\partial x_i} dx = \int_{\partial \Omega} \phi \nu_i dS, \quad i=1,\dots, n$$

where $dS$ is the surface measure. In other words, what your equation is saying is:
$$ \begin{pmatrix}\int_\Omega \frac{\partial \phi}{\partial x_1}dx \\ \vdots \\ \int_\Omega \frac{\partial \phi}{\partial x_n}dx\end{pmatrix}  =\begin{pmatrix} \int_{\partial \Omega} \phi \nu_1 dS\\ \vdots \\ \int_{\partial \Omega} \phi \nu_n dS\end{pmatrix}$$
The proof is simple: just apply the Divergence theorem $n$ times, once for each function $F$ defined below, where $i=1,\dots n$:
$$ F=(F_1,\dots,F_n):\Omega\to\mathbb R^n, F_j(x) = \begin{cases}0 & i\neq j \\ \phi & i=j\end{cases}$$
then $\nabla \cdot F = \partial\phi/\partial x_i$ and $F\cdot \nu = \phi \nu_i$.

I don't know where to find exercises.

Comment: So, relate to my question, about "In the right hand side should be a dot product?". I suppose that the answer is that there is a dot product but is is not written. So, it would be something like 
 $ \phi(1,1,...1,1) \cdot \nu $ ?

Comment: @JuanMuñoz No, it is a vector equation, the left hand side also has no dot product.

Comment: From my understanding, $\nu $ is a vector and $\phi$ is a scalar. So how is finally a scalar the whole expression?

Comment: $\phi$ is scalar but the gradient $\nabla \phi$ is a vector. Finally the whole expression is a vector

Comment: So, the left side is a vector. This means that it is vector equality. (component to component?)

Comment: Yes, that is what I meant. I also updated with the explicit vectors involved